# Extraer dinamicamente dos o tres espacios texto plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo una tabla con unos productos, los cuales los deseo separar por el contenido de las dos o tres primeras palabras según sea su contenido:

```
WITH 
test_data AS
(
SELECT 'GALLETAS SALADAS' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE LECHE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CRACKER CON SABOR A MANTEQUILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS INTEGRALES CON AVENA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS WAFER CON CREMA DE CHOCOLATE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS WAFER CON CREMA SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE MANTEQUILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS SALTIN' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE CHOCOLATE CON CREMA SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON CREMA SABOR A FRESA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BARQUILLOS SABOR A CHOCOLATE CON CREMA SABOR A LECHE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASTEL CON CREMA SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE LECHE CON CREMA DE AVENA Y SABOR A LECHE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON CREMA SABOR A YOGURT FRESA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON AVENA Y CALCIO' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BARQUILLOS CON CREMA SABOR A FRESA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BARQUILLOS RELLENOS CON CREMA DE CHOCOLATE Y AVELLANA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS MINI WAFER CUBIERTAS CON SABOR A CHOCOLATE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS WAFER CON CREMA SABOR A AREQUIPE (DULCE DE LECHE)' AS product FROM dual
)SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1,2) = 0) THEN
             substr(test_data.product, 1, LENGTH(test_data.product))  
        WHEN (INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1, 3) = 0) THEN
             substr(test_data.product, 1, INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1, 2))
        ELSE substr(test_data.product, 1, INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1, 3))
       END
FROM   test_data;
```

**resultado esperado:**

```
GALLETAS SALADAS
GALLETAS DE LECHE
GALLETAS CRACKER
GALLETAS INTEGRALES
GALLETAS WAFER
GALLETAS WAFER
GALLETAS DE MANTEQUILLA
GALLETAS SALTIN
GALLETAS DE CHOCOLATE
GALLETAS CON SABOR
GALLETAS CON CREMA
BARQUILLOS SABOR
PASTEL CON CREMA
GALLETAS DE LECHE
GALLETAS CON CREMA
GALLETAS CON AVENA
BARQUILLOS CON CREMA
BARQUILLOS RELLENOS
GALLETAS MINI
GALLETAS WAFER
```

lo estoy modificando para usar palabras clave en la palabra intermedia `DE` o `CON`, también evaluando el tamaño, pero pues no se antes de complicarme y hacer un montón de lineas si existe alguna forma se simplificarlo.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=292ca4dc48933306858d177cbfbfe1b1)

Answer (score 0):

Un opción es una función en **PL/SQL**:

```
create or replace function fsbExtraer(p_isbTexto varchar2)
return varchar2
is
  nuIzquierda  integer;
  nuDerecha    integer;
  nuCantidad   integer;
  sbPalabra    varchar2(1000);
  sbSalida     varchar2(1000);
Begin
  if p_isbTexto is not null then
     nuDerecha:=0;
     nuCantidad:=0;
     Loop
        nuIzquierda:=nuDerecha+1;
        nuCantidad:=nuCantidad+1;
        nuDerecha:=instr(p_isbTexto,
                         ' ',
                         nuIzquierda
                        );
        if nuDerecha>0 then
           sbPalabra:=substr(p_isbTexto,
                             nuIzquierda,
                             nuDerecha-nuIzquierda
                            );
        Else
           sbPalabra:=substr(p_isbTexto,
                             nuIzquierda
                            );
        End if;
        --
        if nuCantidad=1 then
           sbSalida:=sbPalabra;
        Elsif nuCantidad=2 then
              sbSalida:=sbSalida||' '||sbPalabra;
              exit when upper(sbPalabra) NOT in (upper('DE'),upper('CON'));
        Elsif nuCantidad=3 then
              sbSalida:=sbSalida||' '||sbPalabra;
              exit;
        end if;
        exit when nuDerecha=0;
     End loop;
   End if;
  return(sbSalida);
End fsbExtraer;
```